# Don't know how to get certain result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this kind of table structure.

```
fn |    property    |                              value                              
----+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog
 19 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/123.mov
  4 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/230230230.mp4
 21 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/4142.mov
 20 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/5959.mp4
 22 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/999.mp4
  3 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/Job Interview   Good Example Copeeeee.mp4
 18 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/Screen Shot 2019-03-22 at 13.01.46.png
  8 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/aaall.mp4
  7 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/aasww.mp4
  5 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/awww.mp4
  6 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/brum.mp4
  2 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/test.mov
 19 | filename       | /Users/Shared/catalog/123333.mov
```

I would like to get only values that are not even for same id with filtering only property with names - filename and File_Real_Path. The output should be like this.

```
fn |    property    |              value               
----+----------------+----------------------------------
 19 | File_Real_Path | /Users/Shared/catalog/123.mov
 19 | filename       | /Users/Shared/catalog/123333.mov
```

Here is query I tried but it returns all rows with File_Real_Path even if property with - filename does not exist -

```
select e1.fn, e1.property, e1.value
from metadatas  e1
inner join metadatas as e2
on e1.fn = e2.fn
and e1.property != e2.property
and e1.value != e2.value
where e1.property in ('filename','File_Real_Path')
group by e1.fn, e1.property, e1.value
order by e1.property, e1.value;
```

Hopefully you understood what I want to say about this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Your query works. Also, even without the `group by`. Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=20bd503479c6b452b70dcf5c759c99c0)

Comment: I would use `<` instead of `!=` to avoid symmetric values, as in: `and e1.property < e2.property`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `exists`?

```
select m.*
from metadatas m
where m.property in ('filename', 'File_Real_Path') and
      exists (select 1
              from metadatas2 m2
              where m2.property in ('filename','File_Real_Path') and
                    m2.fn = m.fn and
                    m2.value <> m.value and m2.property <> m.property
             );
```